# How to add an external link to the Desktop menu

Tags: guidewire

PolicyCenter 10.2. I want to add an external link to the Desktop menu to open a new browser window. Is it feasible?

This is a quick POC. In Desktop.pcf I've added

```
<LocationRef
      icon="&quot;queues&quot;"
      iconType="svgFileName"
      location="MyForward()"/>
```

And MyForward.pcf looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PCF
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../pcf.xsd">
  <Forward
    action="MyExternalLinkOpenPortal_Acc.push(&quot;https:google.coml&quot;)"
    allowGoOrPush="false"
    canVisit="true"
    desc="&quot;Hello&quot;"
    id="MyForward">
    <LocationEntryPoint
      signature="MyForward()"/>
  </Forward>
</PCF>
```

MyExternalLinkOpenPortal_Acc is an ExitPoint. The problem is menu item title is empty and PC crashes after I click on it with error ExitPoint.getTitle() Operation not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is functional on the action attribute of a Forward but the default gosu expression can be overridden as described below.  Try using http: or javascript: prefixes to see if that will get you the behavior you are trying for.  Note that the PCF framework places significant constraints on what you can render in favor of easier and more consistent development.  You may not be able to achieve what you're trying to do.

"Other types
of actions can be specified by using the following prefixes: http: causes the browser
to follow the specified plain http link https: causes the browser to follow the specified
plain https link javascript: causes the browser to execute the specified javascript
logout: logs out of the application"

Comment: Useful tip but an error occurs in this case as it tries to call it on the server side. I found that I can set action="Underwriter_MySummary.go(User.util.CurrentUser); MyExitPoint.push(&quot;https://gmail.com&quot;)". It opens a new window but PC page is partially blank and also didn't found a way how to pass CurrentLocation from Desktop.pcf to MyForward to render the current page in PC. CurrentLocation is not available for if I'm on the dashboard